# How to install and configure iFilter PDF for SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Recently installed SharePoint 2010 and all my pdf documents which I uploaded are not having adobe acrobat icon.  Since I am new to SharePoint someone please let me know what I have to install and configure iFilter in my SharePoint 2010? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3):

An iFilter isn't necessary to get the PDF icon displaying in your document libraries.  The iFilter is used in the Search crawling process.  You'll want to follow [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832809) TechNet article to set up the icon.

1. Copy the .gif file that you want to use for the icon to the
   following folder on the server, as appropriate for your version of
   SharePoint:  SharePoint Server 2010 - Drive:\Program Files\Common
   Files\Microsoft Shared\Web server extensions\14\Template\Images
2. Stop IIS at a command prompt by running IISReset /stop
3. Edit the Docicon.xml file to include the .pdf extension.  To do
   this, follow
       these steps:  Start Notepad, and then open the Docicon.xml file.
   The
       Docicon.xml file is located in one of the following folder on
   the
       server:   SharePoint Server 2010- Drive:\Program Files\Common
       Files\Microsoft Shared\Web server extensions\14\Template\Xml
4. Add an entry for the .pdf extension. For example, add a line that is
       similar to the following to the Docicon.xml file, where
       NameofIconFile is the name of the .gif file: `<Mapping
       Key="pdf"  Value="NameofIconFile.gif"/>`
5. On the File menu, click Save, and then quit Notepad.  Start  IIS at
   a command prompt by running IISReset /start

Comment: the question is subtlety tagged "SharePoint-Online" so I suppose this won't help him much

Comment: I think might be a mistag since he says he installed SharePoint recently.  If it isn't a mistag, then I'll delete the post.

Comment: Excellent overview from Eric, there's also a Microsoft article that covers it all: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2293357

Answer (score 1):

step by step instructions can be found [here](http://virtualizesharepoint.com/2011/08/30/configure-pdf-ifilter-v9-for-sharepoint-2010/)

1. Download: Adobe PDF iFilter 9 for 64-bit for SharePoint 2010

[image]

1. Download and extract the contents of "PDFiFilter64installer.zip" to your local drive.
2. Double click "PDFFilter64installer.msi" to launch the installer.

[image]

configure-adobe-ifilter-for-sharepoint-2010-2

4. Follow the instructions in the installer wizard to complete the installation.
5. Download the Adobe Icons from : Download Adobe Icon for SharePoint

configure-adobe-ifilter-for-sharepoint-2010-3

If you don’t like the above icon, you can use the standard icon which comes with Adobe PDF iFilter 9 for 64-bit platforms

C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe PDF iFilter 9 for 64-bit platforms

PDF iFilter 9 for 64-bit platforms icon

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is one more missing step and that is clearly explained either:
1. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2293357
2. http://www.sharepointhints.ch/?p=229

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius

Answer (score 0):

here is an article on Configure PDF iFilter 9 on SharePoint 2010 Server http://anuraggawande.blogspot.in/2012/10/how-to-configure-pdf-ifilter-on.html